# Which one of the five mother sauces is Sauce Messine derived from?

Tags: sauce, organization

I'm organising the sauce recipes I have and I'm uncertain as to where I should place [Sauce Messine](http://www.food.com/recipe/sauce-messine-for-fish-360427). I'm inclined to say it belongs in the bechamel category, or is it a veloute based sauce? I'm not sure. Also where would sauces like parsley and watercress sauce fall in the system of the five mother sauces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sauce Messine should fall into the bechamel category. Velouté sauces incorporate stock rather then cream or milk.

This is a basic answer to the difference in the two, from  [YIANNISLUCACOS](http://www.yiannislucacos.gr/en/q/4358/bechamel-and-veloute-sauce-what-difference#.VnbnPHo8KrU) .

> The difference between velouté and béchamel is that the milk is replaced by a stock, i.e. chicken, beef, fish etc.
>
> In every other respect velouté sauce is almost identical to béchamel.
>
> In general, it is used as a base for a number of white sauces. Its main applications are:
>
> - Base for sauces
> - Base for soups
> - Basic ingredient for mixtures and fillings, as it offers moisture and a rich texture, such as patties, pies, pasta fillings.

As for other sauces with parsley, watercress, or other ingredients, they would fall into certain categories based on the mother sauce base, not the flavors or other additions.

It is a fairly easy internet search to get more information, should you need it.

Comment: Hm. Not so sure. There is no roux and there are eggs beaten over a water bath. A hybrid between Béchamel and Hollandaise?

Comment: @Stephie I do see your point, but I still lean toward bechamel. In reading the recipe, the flour and butter are blended together first and then the other ingredients are added and stirred over the water bath until thickened. I would say this is mostly a matter of a different heating technique and would work equally well in a sauce pan. I look at the water bath in this case as a safety net.